# jekyll permalink failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: jekyll

I want to pretty up my jekyll links, but why is it that when I set `permalink: pretty` in `_config.yml` chrome returns "failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 ()?"

Then when I remove the default setting from my `_config.yml`, my resources return?

edit

just tried it again and the problem applies to my `archive.md` page only.

```
---
layout: landing
title: archive
image: assets/images/riomag.jpg
nav-menu: true
---
<section id="banner" class="style2">
  <div class="inner">
    <header class="major">
      <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
            <h4>{{ page.description }}</h4>
    </header>
      {% if page.image %}<span class="image main"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ page.image }}" alt="" /></span>{% endif %}
  </div>
</section>

<div id="main">

<section id="one" class="tiles">
    {% for post in site.posts limit:tiles-count %}
    {% if site.tiles-source == 'posts' %}
    <article>
      <span class="image">
        <img src="{{ post.image }}" alt="" />
      </span>
      <header class="major">
        <h3><a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}" class="link">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
      </header>
    </article>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for page in site.pages limit:site.tiles-count %}
    {% if site.tiles-source == 'pages' %}
    <article>
      <span class="image">
        <img src="{{ page.image }}" alt="" />
      </span>
      <header class="major">
        <h3><a href="{{ page.url | relative_url }}" class="link">{{ page.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ page.description }}</p>
      </header>
    </article>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

Comment: Did you stop and start Jekyll ? It's needed for config change to take effect.

Comment: yeah. I checked again just to be sure. permalink works when I put it in my frontmatter for posts, no failed resources.

Comment: Could you post the actual file that this is failing on, or even the output your seeing please?

Comment: I added the code from my archive page